# bootstrap responsive utilities

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design

i have this code that I used to create menus for phone only in the header

```
<?php if ($categories) { ?>
<div class="container visible-phone">

  <nav id="menu" class="navbar">
    <div class="navbar-header"><span id="category" class="visible-xs"><?php echo $text_category; ?></span>
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-navbar navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-ex1-collapse"><i class="fa fa-bars"></i></button>
    </div>
    // and other tags that creating the menu successfully
  </nav>

</div>
<?php } ?>
```

and along with this i want to create the vertical menu, only for desktop and for small devices i m hidding it with hidden-xs, which i am creating through

```
<div class="container" id="left-menu">
    <nav id="menu" class="navbar-nav">
    <ul class="nav sidebar">


    <?php foreach ($categories as $category) { ?>
        <?php if($category['children']){?>
        <li class="dropdown-submenu">
        <a href="<?php echo $category['href']; ?>"><?php echo $category['name']; ?></a>
        <div class="dropdown-menu">

          // other tags that creating the menus successfully

        </li>
        <?php }?>
    <?php } ?>

    </ul>
    </nav>
</div>
```

problem is when I do not use visible-phone, in the first horizontal menu, both display fine. but as soon as i use visible-phone for first menu the margin-left property of the subsequent menu of second menu become -196.xxx.

please remember as soon as I remove visible-phone class both menu display correctly on desktop as it should. as I am new user of bootstrap and jquery so your guidance is very important for me.

Thankyou in advance.

also sharing css for submenus

```
.dropdown-submenu {
    position: relative;


}


.dropdown-submenu>.dropdown-menu {
    top: 0;
    left: 100%;
    margin-top: -6px;
    margin-left: -1px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 0 6px 6px 6px;
    -moz-border-radius: 0 6px 6px;
    border-radius: 0 6px 6px 6px;
}

.dropdown-submenu:hover>.dropdown-menu {
    display: block;
}

.dropdown-submenu>a:after {
    display: block;
    content: " ";
    float: right;
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    border-color: transparent;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 5px 0 5px 5px;
    border-left-color: #ccc;
    margin-top: 5px;
    margin-right: -10px;
}

.dropdown-submenu:hover>a:after {
    border-left-color: #fff;
}

.dropdown-submenu.pull-left {
    float: none;
}

.dropdown-submenu.pull-left>.dropdown-menu {
    left: -100%;
    margin-left: 10px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 6px 0 6px 6px;
    -moz-border-radius: 6px 0 6px 6px;
    border-radius: 6px 0 6px 6px;
}
```

Comment: Can you put a Fiddle together with your html?

Comment: .visible-phone is your own class it's not part of Bootstrap's css. You haven't shared your cs

Comment: i think visible-phone is in bootstrap responsive utilities bootstrap-responsive.min.css. in parallel with bootstrap i m using this  stylesheet that i have pasted in original question

Comment: no, bootstrap goes by screen sizes: `xs`, `sm`, `md`, `lg`.

Comment: what version of bootstrap are you using? can you show us your CSS links? `visible-phone` was part of v2 but was replaced in v3 by the corresponding screen sizes so there's no way that class alone is affecting your layout

Comment: bootstrap-responsive.min.css is part of Bootstrap 2. and visible-xs is part of Bootstrap 3. Choose one

Comment: @koala_dev  thanx for the information. I am wrongly using bootstrap 3 with responsive utilities of version 2. how do you think I should render menus depending upon the device?

Comment: ok have used hidden-sm and hidden-lg instead of hidden-phone and hidden-desktop. but submenu i am using is still margin to the left most. and its only when i hide first menu.